# AutoCAD .net API (in process) WIPOUTFRAME system variable

Tags: c#, object, autocad

AutoCAD has a nifty way of changing system variables through its API

Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.SetSystemVariable(string, object)

the string is the system variable name--in my case "WIPEOUTFRAME"

the object is the setting--I want to set it to 0.

I've used the method for other system variables and it works, but not this one.

Instead I get the eInvalidInput error at run time.

I've verified that WIPEOUTFRAME is correct (I can set it via the command line in autoCAD) and I verified that the value is 0.

I've also used the GetSystemVariable(string) method, which returns the setting as an object, to verify the program understands WIPEOUTFRAME, and that it can return a value of 0.  It does.  Also, I've confirmed the type of object it returns: INT16.
I've also passed the object returned by GetSystemVariable to SetSystemVariable and it works! Even when I make sure the value of WIPEOUTFRAME is 0.  It's the only time I got the method to work.  But of course, I want to change the value from 1 to 0, so while it confirms that the method CAN work, passing the same object doesn't help me with changing the value.

I've tried passing the value 0 to the parameter as an object, as an int16 object, as simply 0, as a string, and so on... no success.

Could this be a bug in the API, or can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I worked with another CAD in C# that had a weird COM interface.  I ended up writing brute-force tests to figure out how all of the undocumented features worked.  You might try stuff like using other numeric types or even just a string "0" (even if it appears to be an int16), trying to set it multiple times (probably with a delay between attempts), etc..  In a few cases, I found ways to make things work that made no sense; but, they were reliably reproducible, so I made a wrapper class that went around the COM interface and did those weird things.

Comment: In a few cases, I couldn't figure out how to set a variable's value - the system just wouldn't let me.  But, I did figure out how to write arbitrary code into "Calculator" blocks that I could have the simulation run whenever I wanted; so, I made some Calculator blocks at the right places in the simulation, then I rewrote their code to be a series of variable assignment commands.  Definitely a hack, but it allowed me to change the variable values.

Comment: You might have other conditions to meet, e.g. it might not let you change values while a simulation's running (not sure if that's a valid concept in the particular package that you're working with), or the variable might just be an alias for another location where it's actually stored.

Comment: Thanks @Nat for your comments.  as I mentioned, this is in-process code and I've tried many types, none of which worked.  However--although there are no simulations, but there are transactions the code must take and commit to.  I've tried using the transaction and it did not work.  You've inspired me to try that again, now that I've gotten the exact Type (Int16) which is required.  It worked now!!!  For inspiring my solution +++

Answer (score 1):

Solved--Without locking the application and creating a transaction, the API would not accept the input.